# Making labels stand out on background?

Tags: text, mobile, iphone

A page in my app shows a picture of the user's pet, I'm trying to add a label above the picture that will contain the pet's name. I'm a computer science student who is really bad at UI and am having a difficult time making this label fit in with the rest of the page.

Since the background is white I made the label's text color black to stand out, but it looks pretty bad in my opinion. Here's a picture of the page:

[image: pic]

Can anybody please help a non-UI-savy student make the label above the picture look less like crap?

Edit: Here's the improved version thanks to user287001's suggestions:

[image: finalpic]

Comment: FWIW: Your logo looks like "Dag Lag" to me

Comment: I see what you mean.. I think it looks less like it if you've seen the actual name of the app before this logo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a little decorative font for the name is a must. The bones, hearts etc. background stuff should be faded under the name. The name should be in big size, reduce it only if needed due the space limitations.

[image]

Hopefully you have quite a big selection of background, frame and text styles for different personalities.

The maximum readability of the name is secondary. The user surely knows the name. The presentation of his pet in a pleasant (for the user) style is most important.

Under Construction: This area might be used better by telling something about the pet. The confiquring tasks should not steal this much space from the main screen.

Comment: This is some great advice, thankyou! I've taken your suggestions and created this:  http://imgur.com/a/01S8u.   Let me know what you think! I'm still working on fading the background behind the name of the pet.

Comment: @MarksCode Much better! Try to change the black outlines of the letters to white blur that resides under the actual letters but over the background.(I do not know that much about programming, so I use the application software terms)

Comment: Ok, I removed the black outline and added a transparent gradient to the inside of the name's frame. What do you think? http://imgur.com/a/NhJ9t

Comment: @MarksCode Fine. Maybe a little steeper gradient is possible. It allows a little more backround elements to stay. But the difference would be small.

Comment: @MarksCode consider to publish the final result as an addition to the question. That would be a nice movement which benefits other beginners. If the bottom part is still under construction as I suspected, tell it, too.

Comment: Done. thanks for all the help! I also just asked a question about the buttons on the bottom since I'm pretty lost on how to improve those.